# Load fragment from ASync task

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an async task that when data is loaded it also set an onClick for a star rating bar.

When I user clicks the star rating bar, I want to load a new fragment. I am trying this:

```
package com.example.mike.beerportfoliomaterial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 6/22/15.
 */
public class getReviewToRateJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    String noteWriter;
    String noteID;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;

    public getReviewToRateJSON(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Getting A Taste Note");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

            noteWriter = jsonObject.getString("reviewer");
            String beer = jsonObject.getString("beer");
            noteID = jsonObject.getString("noteID");
            String noteToRead = jsonObject.getString("note");

            TextView note = (TextView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.reviewToRate);
            note.setText(noteToRead);







        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }


        //todo: url to send rating too

        addListenerOnRatingBar(c);

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private void addListenerOnRatingBar(final Context view) {
        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) ((Activity) view).findViewById(R.id.reviewRatingBar);

        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                                        boolean fromUser) {

                //next async task to update online database
                float stars = ratingBar.getRating();

                String s = Float.toString(stars);
                //get user id
                SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
                String userName = prefs.getString("userName", null);
                final String userID = prefs.getString("userID", null);

                String url = "myURL;

                //async task to update rating in database
                new AddNoteRate(c).execute(url);



                Fragment Fragment_four;
                FragmentManager man= ((Activity) view).getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_four = new RateReviews();
                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();



            }
        });
    }

}
```

My big issue is I ca not get it to load a new fragment on these lines:

```
Fragment Fragment_four;
                    FragmentManager man= ((Activity) view).getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction tran = man.beginTransaction();
                    Fragment_four = new RateReviews();
                    tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four);//tran.
                    tran.addToBackStack(null);
                    tran.commit();
```

I get a "cannot resolve method" error on this line:

```
FragmentManager man= ((Activity) view).getSupportFragmentManager();
```

I also tried to change getSupportFragmentManager to getFragmentManager, neith worked.

Answer (score 0):

Activity does not have a getSupportFragmentManager function.  The FragmentActivity class in the v4 support library does.  Cast it as that instead, and make sure your actual Activity derives from that rather than from Activity.

Side note-  this may fail anyway.  A Context is not necessarily an Activity.  In fact it will frequently get wrapped in a ContextWrapper or ContextThemeWrapper.  In either case this code will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a **constructor** in asynctask, passing **activity** as parameter.

**AsyncTask.class**

```
public class AsyncTaskExample extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    Activity atv;
    public AsyncTaskExample (Activity atv)
    {
            this.atv = atv;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)  // contain according to regCheck.php
    {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager;
            fragmentManager = atv.getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main, Fragment_four)
                        .commit();
    }
}
```

**Fragment passing in**

```
AsyncTaskExample task = new AsyncTaskExample( getActivity() );
```